# How can I replace text in multiple svg files with one code?

Tags: javascript, svg, jquery-selectors

I am using the same SVG file twice within the page. I'm trying to change a text inside SVGs based on the language of the page. With the code below, only the text in one SVG file changes and the other does not. What do I need to do to change it in all SVGs?

**SVG code:**

```
<text id="trading-text" class="text1" dx="0" dy="0" transform="translate(-100,0)" fill="#444351">DEFAULT TEXT</text>
```

**JS Code:**

```
let text = "CHANGE TEXT"; 
document.querySelector('[id="trading-text"]').innerHTML= text;
```

Comment: Use ``querySelectorAll`` and chain a forEach on it

Comment: You may want to use the [<switch>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/switch) tag for languages.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get what you really mean by svg file. You also should not have more than one element with the same ID! So add a className like `change-text` to each `text` and use the following code:

```js
const text = "CHANGE TEXT"; 

document.querySelectorAll('.change-text').forEach((node) => {
  node.textContent= text
});
```

Good luck.

Comment: You can have the same id, querySelectorAll will find them, getElementById will only find the first. Is it sensible to have id duplicates.... you're the programmer

Comment: Yes, it do so I edited it to "should not"! you're the programmer as well @Danny'365CSI'Engelman

Comment: once you start to venture in your own shadowDOM realm with Web Components, you will learn duplicates IDs can have value.